# Handling PUT request in React?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I am a beginner in both React and Spring Boot and I realized how this might be a really easy question, but I had a problem in understanding how to handle PUT requests in React. I have a form as the following:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <FormGroup>
        <Label>Description</Label>
        <Input type="text" name="description" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
    </FormGroup>

    <FormGroup>
        <Label>Category</Label>
        <select onChange={this.handleChangeCategory}>{optionList}</select>
    </FormGroup>

    <FormGroup>
         <Label>Date</Label>
         <DatePicker selected={this.state.item.timeStamp} onChange={this.handleChangeDate}/>
    </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

This is the item object in the state:

```
item: {
    timeStamp: new Date(),
    description: ''
    category: {id: '', categoryName: ''}
}
```

And I have an "update" button as the following:

```
expenses.map (expense =>
     <Button size="sm" color="secondary" onClick={ () => this.update(expense.id)}>Update</Button>
```

The update() is as following:

```
async update(id) {
    // I want to populate the form with the data from expense.id the user clicked on
    const response = await fetch(`/api/expenses/${id}`); // GET endpoint from Spring Boot
    const body = await response.json();
    this.setState( {item: body});

    // Handling PUT request
    await fetch(`api/expenses/${id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    });
        updatedItem = {...this.state.item}; // Getting the updated item 
        this.setState({item: updatedItem}); // I want to be able to update the state like this
        this.props.history.push('/expense');
    }
```

I want to be able to populate the form with the data from the expense.id the user clicked on and I had the logic of getting the GET method from the endpoint in Spring Boot but it did not work. I am also confused on how handle the PUT request after the user updated the form. Sorry if it is a stupid question. Any help would be appreciated, thanks alot!

Comment: what is the response of your put request ? .

Comment: from the springboot endpoint?

Comment: Is the API endpoint is correct? Try to call the same API using postman and see if ur able to get 200 or success code.

Comment: yes, i checked with postman previously and it is correct and the database gets updated